# Rails uploads (carrierwave) are extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

an 1MB file takes 3+ minutes to upload. (the files are uploaded to S3, I am using CarrierWave 0.5.8 over fog 1.1.1).

ideas?

Comment: Did you find out what it was?

Comment: not really, however my investigation revealed that the slow down was not in rails (passenger), it was between the browser and apache, browser was just uploading to apache too slow, and as soon as apache handed the file over to passenger, it took negligible time to process it.